Sub-gaussian norm
Consider the following definition of a $\sigma$-sub-gaussian random variable:
$$\mathbb{E}\exp\left(\lambda\left(X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)\right)\leqslant\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^{2}\sigma^{2}}{2}\right)$$
I need to prove that the following function is a norm over the space of centered sub-gaussian random variables:
$$\|X\|_{vp}=\min\left\{ \sigma\,|\,\text{X is $\sigma$-sub-gaussian}\right\}$$
I don't know how to approach the "minimal" aspect. For example, in order to show homogeneity, I can show that $Cx$ is $\left|C\right|\sigma$-sub-gaussian, but I don't know how should I show that it is the minimal value:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\lambda\left(CX\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(C\lambda\right)X\right]\leqslant\exp\left(\frac{C^{2}\lambda^{2}\sigma^{2}}{2}\right)$$
For the positive definiteness property, I tried to use Jensen's inequality to get that $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\lambda X\right)\right]=1$, but I'm not sure I can conclude based on that $X=0$ a.s.:
$$1=\exp\left(\mathbb{E}\left[\lambda X\right]\right)\overset{}{\leqslant}\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\lambda X\right)\right]\overset{}{\leqslant}\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^{2}0^{2}}{2}\right)=1$$
And there is the triangle inequality property I don't know how to approach as well.

For any centered random variable $X$, let $\Sigma(X) = \{\sigma \geq 0 : X \text{ is } \sigma \text{ sub-Gaussian} \}$. Thus, $\|X\|_{vp} = \inf \Sigma(X)$.
Let us begin with positive definiteness. Consider the random variable $X = 0$ a.s. Consequently, $\exp(\lambda X) = 1$ a.s. for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X)] = 1.
\end{align*}
Since for all $\sigma \geq 0$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $1 \leq \exp(\lambda^2\sigma^2/2)$, $\Sigma(X)$ is the set of non-negative reals. Consequently, $\|X\|_{vp} = 0$.
Let us move to homogeneity. Let $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X$ be a centered sub-Gaussian random variable. Let $Y = sX$. Clearly, $Y$ is also a centered random variable. Moreover, for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma \in \Sigma(X)$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda Y)] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda sX)] \leq \exp\left( \frac{\lambda^2s^2\sigma^2}{2}\right),
\end{align*}
where the last relation follows from sub-Gaussianity of $X$ applied with $\lambda' = \lambda s$. Thus, for all $\sigma \in \Sigma(X)$, $|s|\sigma \in \Sigma(Y)$. Consider $\sigma \notin \Sigma(X)$. This implies that there exists $\lambda_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda_{0}X)] > \exp\left( \frac{\lambda_0^2\sigma^2}{2}\right).
\end{align*}
This also implies that there exists $\lambda_1 = \lambda_0/s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda_{1}Y)] = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\frac{\lambda_{1}}{s} \cdot (sX) \right)\right] = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda_{0}X)] > \exp\left( \frac{\lambda_0^2\sigma^2}{2}\right) = \exp\left( \frac{\lambda_1^2(s\sigma)^2}{2}\right).
\end{align*}
Thus for every $\sigma \notin \Sigma(X)$, $|s|\sigma \notin \Sigma(Y)$. It is sufficient to just consider the case where with $|s|$ as we only consider non negative values in $\sigma(W)$ for any centered random variable $W$. Thus, $\Sigma(Y) = \{|s|\sigma : \sigma \in \Sigma(X)\}$. Consequently, $\|Y\|_{vp}  = |s| \cdot \|X\|_{vp} = \|sX\|_{vp}$.
For the condition of triangle inequality, let $X$ and $Y$ be two centered random variables. Clearly $X+Y$ is also a centered random variable. Also, let $p, q > 0$ such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$. For all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma_1 \in \Sigma(X)$ and $\sigma_2 \in \Sigma(Y)$,  we have,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda(X + Y))] & = \mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda X) \cdot \exp(\lambda Y)] \\
& \leq \left( \mathbb{E}[\exp(p\lambda X)]\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \cdot \left(\mathbb{E}[\exp(q\lambda Y)] \right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \\
& \leq \left( \exp\left(\frac{p^2\lambda^2\sigma_1^2}{2} \right)\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \cdot \left( \exp\left(\frac{q^2\lambda^2\sigma_2^2}{2} \right)\right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \\
& \leq \exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2(p\sigma_1^2 + q\sigma_2^2)}{2} \right).
\end{align*}
In the second step, we used Holder's inequality. If we choose $p = 1 + \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}$, then $q = 1 + \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_2}$ and consequently,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda(X + Y))]  \leq \exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2(\sigma_1 + \sigma_2)^2}{2} \right)
\end{align*}
implying that $\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 \in \Sigma(X+Y)$. Thus, $\Sigma(X+Y) \supseteq \{\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 : \sigma_1 \in \Sigma(X), \sigma_2 \in \Sigma(Y)\}$. Consequently
\begin{align*}
\inf \Sigma(X+Y) \leq \inf \Sigma(X) + \inf \Sigma(Y),
\end{align*}
or equivalently, $\|X+Y\|_{vp} \leq \|X\|_{vp} + \|Y\|_{vp}$, as required.

Thank you very much!
